# How to get response headers parameter from Axios get request?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, promise, axios

I want to read the csrf token from the response header of the axios get request which I am going to send with the axios post request as request header. My code is as below :

```
const FileApi= {
  list: (type:string,period:string): AxiosPromise<FilesL[]> =>
    axios.get(`upload/${type}/${period}`)
      .then(res=> {console.log(res.headers.get("X-CSRF-TOKEN"))}),
  upload: (file:File,type:string,period:string): AxiosPromise<string> => {
    return axios.post(`file/upload/${type}/${period}`,form,{
      headers :{
        'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data',
        'token' : X-CSRF-TOKEN,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

I am not able to get the token from the get request and so the post request is not functioning as the X-CSRF-TOKEN is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Should just be `res.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN']`

Comment: It is throwing error when written with res. I think it is returning a promise so we cannot fetch the data like that.

Comment: How are you calling the function? Your type response is wrong on `list`, it just returns a `Promise<void>` as you're not returning anything from the `.then`